# Writing 1xN char array to excel using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

I have a [1x117 char] (AKA 1x117 character array) that I need to write into a single cell in excel. Before doing so I did the follow:

```
x = [1x117 char];
x = cellstr(x);
xlswrite('test.xls',x )
```

However the excel spreadsheet is empty. I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Comment: Works for me: `x = {'bananas'}; xlswrite('test.xls',x)` Gives me one cell with "bananas" in it.

Comment: Do you have Excel installed or just OpenOffice.org, etc.?  I don't think you can write xls without Excel... could be wrong.

Comment: @chappjc I have excel.